# TextureView in a Fragment never calls onSurfaceTextureAvailable

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've seen lots of examples using TextureView in a main Activity but I'm trying to put it into a Fragment.

I've created the simplest example possible and its onCreateView is being called, onActivityCreated as well but onSurfaceTextureAvailable isn't being called after passing back the TextureView.

What am I missing ?

Thanks
G

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    }
}

public class TextureViewFragment  extends Fragment
implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    private TextureView         mTextureView;

     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          mTextureView = new TextureView(getActivity());
          mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
          mTextureView.setOpaque(false);    
         return mTextureView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
        int height) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    }
}


activity_fullscreen.xml:

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="#0099cc"
             tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

     <fragment class="com.example.test.TextureViewFragment"
               android:id="@+id/graphTextureView"
               android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: In fact, if I manually create my listener passing in the TextureView and put the TextureView into the activity_fullscreen.xml it ALSO won't call onSurfaceTextureAvailable!  

Now I'm really confused.

` <TextureView
    android:id="@+id/graphTextureView"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />`

and:

` setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
  TextureView v = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.graphTextureView);

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693194/textureview-onsurfacetextureavailable-never-called-inside-relativelayout-inside/16897762#16897762

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `TextureView` must have a nonzero size and be visible. Based on the comment, the `layout_width` was set to `0px`. Change that to a nonzero value.

(Old question but posting answer for posterity)

Answer (score 1):

You should add 'android:hardwareAccelerated=true' to your AndroidManifest.xml.

TextureView needs hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextureView` should be in a layout xml file. Instead of using `new` to instantiate it you should get it using something like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_video, container, false);
mTextureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_texture_view);
```

Then in your **layout_video.xml** file you need a `TextureView` with id **video_texture_view**