# textureview onSurfaceTextureAvailable never called inside relativelayout inside fragment

Tags: android

onSurfaceTextureAvailable in VideoView is never called...
I have this view that is holding the textureview.

```
public class MyMediaPlayer extends RelativeLayout{

Context mContext;
VideoView player;//this is a custom textureview that streams video

public MyMediaPlayer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context; 
    init();
}
public MyMediaPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context; 
    init();
}
public MyMediaPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mContext = context; 
    init();
}
private void init() {
    setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);    
    player = new VideoView(mContext);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    addView(player,lp);
}
public void setURL(String url){
    player.setVideoPath(url);
}
public void start(){
    player.start();
}

}
```

VideoView is set up like this:

```
public class VideoView extends TextureView {

public VideoView(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    initVideoView();
}

public VideoView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    initVideoView();
}

public VideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mContext = context;
    initVideoView();
}

public void initVideoView() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Initializing video view.");
    videoHeight = 0;
    videoWidth = 0;
    setFocusable(false);
    setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
}
SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener = new SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Surface texture now avaialble.");
        surfaceTexture = surface;
        openVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Resized surface texture: " + width + '/' + height);
        surfaceWidth = width;
        surfaceHeight = height;
        boolean isValidState =  (targetState == STATE_PLAYING);
        boolean hasValidSize = (videoWidth == width && videoHeight == height);
        if (mediaPlayer != null && isValidState && hasValidSize) {
            start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(final SurfaceTexture surface) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Destroyed surface number " + number);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(final SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }
};
}
```

MyMediaPlayer is setup in a xml of a fragment.
If i place the VideoView inside the fragment then everything works fine.
But if it is in mymediaplayer inside the fragment onSurfaceTextureAvailable is never called.

Comment: is it working now? could you share sample solution or example project?

Answer (score 27):

`onSurfaceTextureAvailable` doesn't seem to get called if the `SurfaceTexture` is already available. You can check if it is available and call your `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` method like below.

```
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

/*
 * onSurfaceTextureAvailable does not get called if it is already available.
 */
if (view.isAvailable()) {
    onSurfaceTextureAvailable(view.getSurfaceTexture(), view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: But how could the surface be available and onSurfaceTextureAvailable not being called? I had a look into the TextureView source code, and I can't see that to be possible.

Comment: If you call `setSurfaceTextureListener` after the surface is available, you won't get the `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` callback.

Comment: what is `view` in your context?

Comment: I think `view` is supposed to be the same as `textureView` on the first line.

Answer (score 20):

As for me ,the key to solve the problem is that add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" for the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml .

You can use TextureView in a Scrolling-Container(Such as ListView,ScrollView,ViewPager etc) only if the activity for the TextureView with hardwareAccelerated property on.

[The last few words in this blog mentioned that](http://www.ptt.cc/bbs/AndroidDev/M.1355248043.A.523.html)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: My issue was fixed by manually calling `onSurfaceTextureAvailable`. I don't think setting `hardwareAccelerated="true"` will help many new projects, since hardware acceleration is enabled by default for [Target API level >= 14](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).

Answer (score 12):

In my case I initially had my `TextureView` invisible and then loaded after fetching some data and this was causing `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` not to be called. I am guessing that for `TextureView` to be said to be 'available', it must be visible. My solution was to just make the `TextureView` visible from the start.

Answer (score 12):

You need to enable hardware acceleration to use TextureView. If you don't, its callback methods will not be called. Just pout that in your activity's onCreate method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Years later, I come across with the same problem again, and your answer saved my life again :)

Answer (score 4):

I have met the same issue, `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` never called. Finally I found my `textureview` is invisible before `setSurfaceTextureListener`. So check status of `textureview` at first.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Next time, try posting advice like this in the comments section

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem , strangely resolved it with the following code

```
videoPreview = (TextureView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)videoPreview.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 130;
params.width = 508;
videoPreview.setLayoutParams(params);
videoPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```

More strangely if i set only the width or the height that dosent work either.

Comment: But what is the reason of the solution? To place a random size?

Comment: i really don't know .. i was experimenting and that's what worked out for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but the situation was due to a bigger problem: the view was not laying itself out properly. The parent layout view (a custom ViewGroup) was not calling View.measure(...) correctly on the texture view's parent. I just had to fix up my ViewGroup control.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake is set TextureView visibility as InVisible. so the callback didn't invoke.

Answer (score 0):

try to put `mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener()` in `onCreate()`.

RootCause is that: `onCreate()` -> `drawUI` -> `getHardwareLayer()` -> `callback SurfaceTextureListener`.
So to fix this issue: `setSurfaceTextureListener()` before UI draw or redraw the UI.