# Play a video through a url with MediaPlayer not working on Android 9

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to play a video through a url, it works on android <9

but on android 9 it's not working

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                mediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);
}
```

UPDATE:

I'm trying to play a video through a direct url, it works on android <9

but on android 9 it's not working this code was working before android 9 came it was working well but with android 9 not working anymore

this is the full class :

```
public class FeatureFragment extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {


    TextureView surfaceView;
    private String videoPath = "direct url.mp4";


    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new FeatureFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feature_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        surfaceView = view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        surfaceView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        try {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        surfaceTexture = null;
        videoPath = null;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
}
```

and here is the layout which contains only the TextureView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question and answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693194/textureview-onsurfacetextureavailable-never-called-inside-relativelayout-inside) Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thank bro, but it didn't

Comment: share your logcats

Comment: can you provide the code where is method is called?

Comment: logcat keep repeating these three lines:                                                       
 E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
E/MediaPlayerNative: Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0xd93e3920, mCurrentState=0  E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)

Comment: Have you enabled hardware acceleration and try to set `surfaceView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);` in `onCreateView(..).`

Comment: Yes I did but nothing

Comment: Why do you use `android:visibility="gone"`and `tools:visibility="visible"`. Try to use only `android:visibility="visible"` and never change the visibility.

Comment: I've tried but nothing is changed

Comment: I've opened an issue in google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117854159

Comment: @MusabAlothman hello there, same problem here, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: @EagerToLearn I am afraid I don't, but I will try the solution that you've suggested