# Why doesn't the activity resume properly?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to get a program to correctly resume after onPause and onStop are called as a result of pressing the rightmost button to look at the open applications or making the phone go to sleep. I am not familiar with what the correct calls are. I have looked up some information about this but all I have found are people saying to call super.onPause in onPause and super.onResume in the onResume and then write my code. This code is not mine however and crashes upon resume with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.startPreview()' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.startPreview()' on a null object reference
```

The code can be found at: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/LegacyCameraConnectionFragment.java

I have **two** questions about all of this:

- I can get the camera to restart properly by commenting out lines 185-187 but I do not know if this is the correct way to go about this. Comments? Thoughts?
- And even if this works, the main activity does not restart. This is the actual main issue here. I also imagine something must be wrong with this code but cannot figure out what it is. Any advice on how to fix it?

Main activity code link:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/CameraActivity.java

Comment: This answer is probably what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729478/2711811 - add the listener call at line 152.  Seems like a bug in the example -or- a race condition not accounted for.  Basically the camera is set to null onPause but the `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` (which sets the camera) is not called again because the view is already available.  (The main activity is not starting because one of its fragments failed during onResume.)

Comment: @Andy But why does commenting out the lines I mention above not restart the main activity? since ```onsurfaceTextureAvailable``` was already run, shouldn't everything be in place already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes that I made and mention in the question did not solve the problem for some reason. I imagine it has to do with the callback not being set properly after onStop is called or the new backgroundthread changing something?

To fix it, I added

```java
textureView.getSurfaceTextureListener().onSurfaceTextureAvailable(textureView.getSurfaceTexture(), textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
```

before line 152 in the Legacy... .java file.